# Swift not receiving or showing complete server response for a POST request using URLSession.data

Tags: swift, urlsession

I have following code snippet of a function that makes http(s) requests in my SwiftUI app:

```
 func load<T: Codable>(_ resource : Resource<T>) async throws -> T {
        var request = URLRequest(url:resource.url)
        switch resource.method {
            case .get(let queryItems):
                var components = URLComponents(url: resource.url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
                if !queryItems.isEmpty {
                    components?.queryItems = queryItems
                } 
                guard let url = components?.url else {
                    throw NetworkError.badRequest
                }
                request = URLRequest(url:url)
        case .post(let data):
            request.httpMethod = resource.method.name
            request.httpBody = data
        case .delete:
            request.httpMethod = resource.method.name
        }
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw NetworkError.invalidResponse
        }
        print("Here is httpResponse")
        print(httpResponse)
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
        guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(resource.modelType, from: data) else {
            print("print error")
            print("\(data.debugDescription)")
            throw NetworkError.decodingError
        }
        print(result)
        return result
    }
```

When executed with certain configuration/payload, it produces following output:

```
Here is httpResponse
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000097ee80> { URL: http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    );
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 18 Jun 2023 17:33:40 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        0
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin,
        "Access-Control-Request-Method",
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
    );
    "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "X-Frame-Options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "X-XSS-Protection" =     (
        0
    );
} }
400
Done printing httpResponse
```

However if I invoke same post URL from command line using same config/payload as what above swift program has:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"emailAddress":"hello@example.com","password":"xxyyvv"}'
```

Output is following:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 62
>
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 18 Jun 2023 17:27:08 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
{"error":true,"reason":"Account is not yet activated. Check your email and click on the link in the email to activate the account.","response":""}
```

My questions/observations:

1. In the swift output why I am not able to see the last line that's visible from curl - a json {"error"....}
2. Whenever server returns 400 my code is not able to decode the "data" and throws decoding exception even though resource.modelType conforms to the json that is returned in the event of 400 from server.
3. How do I capture this error json so I can decode it into a Swift struct?

Note that for any 200 response that server returns I am able to capture the returned json and decode it successfully.

**Update 19 Jun 2023:**
This issue is resolved. It was my mistake on how I was sending the JSON from server. The JSON was incorrect that was being sent from server and so JSON decoding was failing in the swift code. Thanks to CouchDeveloper who pointed me in the right direction and helped me troubleshoot it.

Comment: In the Swift code, you need to print the body of the response which is represented by the `data` parameter. Note also the value of the "Content-Type" response header, which is "application/json". That means, your data octets are encoded as UTF-8 which represents the JSON.

Comment: Where is the equivalent of the `-d` parameter in the Swift code? And actually `invalidResponse` will never be thrown.

Comment: @vadian - the request.httpBody is already set above in the code - that code I have not shared. The server receives payload correctly - I have confirmed that.

Comment: I updated my entire method and added a observation at the end of the message alongwith other 2 questions.

Comment: When the server returns status code 400, _frequently_, it will be decoded as HTML. Better of course, one would specify a generic error representation returned as JSON. So, before you start using your JSON decoder, you must check the Content-Type header, and then according to that value, encode the data accordingly. For a quick test, just encode the data to a string which is readable, so you can see similar responses than what you get with cURL. This also answers question 3). Define a decodable structure which represents an error, and the server needs to send an error response with that JSON.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper if you see the output of where i print httpresponse it does say the content as json:    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    ); but will try to convert it to String and see if that works.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use debugger to print data as a String (best effort): Set a breakpoint, then use `po String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as NSString`, where `data` is the variable returned from the response tuple. This is just for quick testing, to get a clue what's going on.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - you were right - if I decode data as String then I get that json response from server as the String. So are you saying server is not sending the response as JSON but as String and so is the issue in Swift not be able to decode it as a appropriate struct that conforms to the json? Or is there some issue in my Swift code? I have to have two conditional paths now - where in success - I decode data as a Struct but in case of specifically 400 server error I have to capture it as String? Or in any non 200 response I will have to capture it as String? Thanks.

Comment: Or is this a bug in Swift that even if the server is sending "Content-Type: application/json" - it is not able to decode the response into appropriate Struct?

Comment: It's very unlikely you hit a problem with the system's JSON decoder. What you can do to further narrow down the problem: print out the data as decoded string, assuming its character encoding is UTF-8. Then, when this is HTML or JSON you see it immediately. When it is JSON, take that string an input it in a "JSON Linter" (there are severals in the Internet, just search for it). Your JSON should be syntactic correct. Whether you can use your Decodable to get it decoded, depends whether the returned (valid) JSON can actually be decoded to this Swift struct.

Comment: You are right with your observation, that you may need _two_ different decoders which each decode to a different Swift representation (aka struct), one for your expected _success_ response, and one for your _error_ response. In your project, you may define a layer where you implement the access to the endpoint, and ideally, you can also specify those two decoders. Alternatively, just provide the success decoder. When there is an error response, parse it and construct a suitable Swift.Error and throw it.

Comment: Thanks @CouchDeveloper ! I found the problem - the json returned from the server was incorrect. The response field should have been nil/null instead of an empty string and now my code is working as expected - swift decoding works just fine. Thanks for patiently guiding me to troubleshoot this issue!